# Parameterizing a Diophantine Equation of Degree 2

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to solve a problem I found online and after fiddling around with the variables, I've arrived at the equation: $$x^2+x^2y^2+y^2=4z^2; 0 < x \le y; z \le 10^{10}$$
The problem asks for integral values $x$, $y$ and $z$, but the maximum value for $z$ is too large to try and test all possible combinations of $x$ and $y$.

I've coded something up to test the smaller values of $x$ and $y$ and, with the help of OEIS, have arrived at these:
$$x=2k; y = 8k^2; 1 \le k$$
$$x=8(k+1)^2; y = 2(k+1)(16k^2+32k+15); 0\le k$$
but these don't account for other values like $(x:112,y:418)$ and $(x:418,y:1560)$.

I've done some Googling too, which led me to [Diophantine Equations entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) on Wikipedia, but the parameterization guide lost me right after I've generated some non-trivial solutions for the equation.

Is there an equation or a set of equations to generate all possible values? If not, would more information help in getting the parameterizations?

Also, for future Diophantine equations, is there a rule of thumb or something I could attempt first to have the parameterizations?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331734/infinitely-many-positive-integers-n-such-that-n21-mid-1-cdot-2-cdot-5-c/2331798#2331798

Comment: @b12629 Can you please specify the source of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I do have an algorithm that keeps tings in reasonable size. I'm going to use other letters.

You are looking at
$$ (u^2 + 1)(v^2 + 1)= w^2 + 1 $$
Fix any integer $u \geq 1.$ Next check all $-1-u \leq v \leq 1+u$
for solutions to
$$ w^2 - (1+u^2) v^2 = u^2  $$
From what I can see, there are at most 11 such $(w,v)$ pairs.
Next, the relevant automorphism matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 u^2 + 1 & 2 u^3 + 2u  \\
 2u & 2 u^2 + 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is, for each such $(w,v)$ pair, you get a new solution from
$$ (w,v)  \mapsto \; \; \; \color{red}{ \left( \; \; \;  (2u^2+1) w + ( 2u^3 + 2u) v \; , \; \; 2uw + ( 2 u^2 + 1) v \; \; \; \right)}  $$
The reason to begin with some negative $v$ is to catch surprises. The predictable small positive solutions are $(w=u, v=0)$ and $(w = u^2-u+1, v=u-1)$
and $(w = u^2+u+1, v=u+1)$  there are occasional surprises, beginning with $u=8, 12, 18, 21,...$   Let's see, for a fixed $u,$  you take $|v| \leq 1+u,$ check for when $u^2 + (u^2 + 1)v^2$  is another square, call that $w^2.$ Put pairs $(w,v)$ and $(w,-v)$ into a list ordered by $v$

```
u=203

 w^2 - 41210 v^2 = 41209 =  7^2 29^2

Thu Aug 27 18:28:05 PDT 2020

w:  203  v:  0  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  837  v:  4  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  41007  v:  202  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  41413  v:  204  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  41007 ,  -202
w:  2059663  v:  10146  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  837 ,  -4
w:  16731057  v:  82418  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  203 ,  0

 back step  :       3   u:  203
Thu Aug 27 18:28:06 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 41210 v^2 = 41209 =  7^2 29^2
```

Alright, by Cayley-Hamilton, the solutions split up into a small number of orbits of Fibonacci type,
$$ v_{j+2} = (4u^2 + 2)v_{j+1} - v_j $$
When $u=8,$ we have

$$ v_{j+2} = 258 \; v_{j+1} - v_j $$
$$ -128, 0, 128, 33024, 8520064,..  $$
$$  -30, 2, 546, 140866,.. $$
$$  -9, 7, 1815, 468263... $$
$$ -7, 9, 2329, 600873, ...  $$
$$ -2, 30, 7742, 1997406,...  $$
$$  0, 128, 33024, 8520064,..  $$
$$   2, 546, 140866, 36342882,...$$
$$  7, 1815, 468263, 120810039,...$$
$$  9, 2329, 600873, 155022905,... $$
As you can see, there is considerable repetition, and the $v$ values grow rapidly in each sequence. Writing it this way, the fixed $u$ value and a $v$ value give
$w = \sqrt{u^2 + (u^2 + 1)v^2}$
You will find that sticking to one of the $v$ sequences causes $w$ to obey the same rule,

$$ w_{j+2} = (4u^2 + 2)w_{j+1} - w_j $$

About when to stop, as $v$ gets large we find $w \approx uv.$

BUT WAIT, THERE'S MORE.

The predictable small non-negative solutions to $w = \sqrt{u^2 + (u^2 + 1)v^2}$ are $w=u, v=0,$
then $w= u^2 - u+1, v = u-1$  and $w = u^2 + u + 1, v = u + 1.$   One of the surprise additions comes when $u = 2 t^2,$ in which case $w = 2t^3 + t , v = t$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with integrals but perhaps solutions for the individual variables might yield ideas. Given:
$$x^2+x^2y^2+y^2=4z^2$$

$$x = \frac{± \sqrt{4 z^2 - y^2}}{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} \land y^2 + 1\ne0$$
$$y = \frac{± \sqrt{4 z^2 - x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \land x^2 + 1\ne0$$
$$z =\frac{ ± \sqrt{x^2 (y^2 + 1) + y^2)}}{2}$$
The last equation looks like safest since it involves only sums under the radical and no danger of division by zero. Now, given $\quad (0<x<y)$:

$$z =\frac{ ± \sqrt{1^2 (2^2 + 1) + 2^2)}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3^2}}{2}$$
$$z =\frac{ ± \sqrt{1^2 (12^2 + 1) + 12^2)}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{17^2}}{2}$$
$$z =\frac{ ± \sqrt{2^2 (3^2 + 1) + 3^2)}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{7^2}}{2}$$
$$z =\frac{ ± \sqrt{2^2 (8^2 + 1) + 8^2)}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{18^2}}{2}$$
$$z =\frac{ ± \sqrt{4^2 (32^2 + 1) + 32^2)}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{132^2}}{2}$$

An interesting note is that whenever $y=x+1$ there is a perfect square under the radical.  This is just busywork math I'm offering but I hope, as I suggested above, that it may help with your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the primitive solutions. For a given value of $x$, we need to solve the generalized Pell's equation $4z^2-(x^2+1)y^2=x^2$.

I don't have a proof yet. But from some results obtained via a python code, values of $x$ satisfies following recurrence.

$x(1)=2,x(2)=8,x(n)=4x(n-1)-x(n-2)$

There are few known algorithms for solving generalized Pell's equation. I guess it can be simplified further.

First few primitive triples are

```
(2, 8, 9)
(2, 144, 161)
(2, 2584, 2889)
(2, 46368, 51841)
(8, 30, 121)
(8, 546, 2201)
(8, 7742, 31209)
(30, 112, 1681)
(30, 28928, 434161)
(112, 418, 23409)
(418, 1560, 326041)
(1560, 5822, 4541161)
(5822, 21728, 63250209)
(21728, 81090, 880961761)
```

EDIT: Unfortunately, this doesn't generate all the solutions. Triple such as $(144, 9790, 704897)$ and $(546, 37120, 10133777)$ cannot be obtained by above method.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+x^2y^2+y^2=4z^2\tag{1}$$

$$x^2(1+y^2)+y^2=(2z)^2$$

Let $Y=\frac{2z}{y}, X=\frac{x}{y}$ then we get
$$Y^2-(1+y^2)X^2=1\tag{2}$$

We consider equation $(2)$ as Pell's equation for fixed $y$.
Small solutions are given below.

```
            (x, y, z) 
            (8, 2, 9)
            (144, 2, 161)
            (32, 4, 66)
            (72, 6, 219)
            (128, 8, 516)
            (200, 10, 1005)
            (288, 12, 1734)
            (392, 14, 2751)
            (512, 16, 4104)
            (648, 18, 5841)
            (800, 20, 8010)
            (968, 22, 10659)
            (1152, 24, 13836)
            (1352, 26, 17589)
            (1568, 28, 21966)
            (1800, 30, 27015)
            (2048, 32, 32784)
            (2312, 34, 39321)
            (2592, 36, 46674)
            (2888, 38, 54891)
            (3200, 40, 64020)
            (3528, 42, 74109)
            (3872, 44, 85206)
            (4232, 46, 97359)
            (4608, 48, 110616)
```