# When is $4a^2+4b^2+4a+4b+1$ a square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Is it possible to determine when $$4a^2+4b^2+4a+4b+1 = ((2a+2b)+1)^2-8ab = (2a+1)^2+4(b^2+b)$$ is a perfect square, assuming $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b>0$? I've tried writing it in a few different forms but I'm not sure if there's a strategy to approach this.

Comment: You can post your different forms as "context".

Comment: The most promising idea I can think of is writing $(2a+1)^2+(2b+1)^2-1$. Then the problem reduces to finding solutions to $m^2+n^2=p^2+1$ with $m,n$ odd (and thus $p$ odd by mod $2$).

Comment: you have $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + z^2$  where $x,y$   and therefore $z$ are odd.  There are infinitely many nontrivial answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution of Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842447/solution-of-diophantine-equation) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(2a%2B1)%5E2%2B(2b%2B1)%5E2%3D(2c%2B1)%5E2%2B1%24&p=1). Note your result is odd, say it's $(2c + 1)^2$. Since your expression can also be written as $(2a + 1)^2 + (2b + 1)^2 - 1$, we get $(2a + 1)^2 + (2b + 1)^2 = (2c + 1)^2 + 1$. This is the proposed duplicate question with $a$ and $c$ switched around (note Will Jagy's comment above also indicates this).

Comment: one of my answers on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331734/infinitely-many-positive-integers-n-such-that-n21-mid-1-cdot-2-cdot-5-c/2331798#2331798

Comment: @A.B FYI, note that [Integral solutions of hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$](/q/351491) is about a somewhat more general question (i.e., where the $3$ variables don't have to all be odd), with it having quite a few answers & different approaches.